# What SNMP library for .NET makes traps, sets or gets simple?

Tags: .net, networking, network-protocols, snmp

What are the best SNMP libraries to use with .NET?  Specifically for listening for traps or sending set or get requests.

Comment: Good question....I've been looking for something to replace the snmp code I wrote that parses output from http://www.net-snmp.org/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am using the [Sharp SNMP Suite (#SNMP)](http://www.codeplex.com/sharpsnmplib) : LGPL, Mono compatible, developed in C# 3.0, has very good API.

Comment: Hmmm...  Support .NET Framework 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, .NET Compact Framework 3.5, and Mono 2.8+.

Support for .NET Framework 2.0 and 3.0 will expire on April 12, 2011. #SNMP release BigDipper (7.0) will no longer support these two .NET versions.

Comment: Starting from 8.0 release (7.6 is an Alpha of 8.0), #SNMP is released under MIT/X11 + BSD 3 Clause. LGPL is no longer used, as it is not mobile platform friendly.

Answer (score 4):

Hi as the author of #SNMP, I try my best to be unbiased here :)

I have a blog post here which is a simple evaluation report.

http://www.lextm.com/index.php/2007/12/product-review-snmp-libraries-for-net-evaluation-report/

In my opinion, PowerSNMP is the leading one which has both complete feature set and simple/natural API. There are many commercial and open source products you can evaluate yourself to see which one meets your special needs.

Which one is the best? This bases on which subset of SNMP features you need and how big your budget is. :)

Comment: Time passes by so fast. Now #SNMP starts to support v3 (based on SNMP#Net), which brings the project forward to a higher level.

Answer (score 1):

here's a library and a few examples http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/malcolmcrowe/SnmpLib11232005011613AM/SnmpLib.aspx

Comment: #SNMP Suite started from Malcolm's project, and now it provides much more than that. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've personally used Adventnet's [.NET SNMP API](http://www.webnms.com/net-snmp/index.html) for snmp work. It's now been renamed to WebNMS. I have code running based on this API several places, that has just worked and keeps on working 24/7.

Recommended for lots of examples and stability. Also it's fast. Seems though that there are several other .NET SNMP libraries that have come since I used SNMP last that might be worth checking out. ex: #SNMP, which has been referenced to in other replies.

Comment: If you refer to http://www.webnms.com/net-snmp/index.html, then I think those guys just did a rename(?). SNMP v3 support is still missing, while even if #SNMP we start to support v3.

Comment: Yea, seems like it. Doesn't look like they've updated the their .NET SNMP API yet. I'm looking forward to testing #SNMP in any upcoming snmp projects. looking very promising