# How to use open source net-snmp library in C#

Tags: c#, wrapper, snmp, net-snmp

I want to use net-snmp library in C#, do I need to write some wrappers around this C++ library or there are any ready made wrappers available?

Comment: Like @dlev pointed out, a managed library is better, and you do have other C# libraries to choose from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146766/what-is-the-best-snmp-library-to-use-with-net

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that particular library has a C# wrapper, but you can try [SnmpSharpNet](http://www.snmpsharpnet.com/).